# Oracle wm_concat query returns result set with odd characters

Tags: oracle, function, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

My Oracle query produces the correct result set, but data is being presented with odd characters as you can see by the blocks in the picture below.

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_VSEi5_hEznA/TDtsnM9HDnI/AAAAAAAAAD8/zoEzbEaKB9s/blocks.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_VSEi5_hEznA/TDtsnM9HDnI/AAAAAAAAAD8/zoEzbEaKB9s/blocks.jpg)

Any reason that you can think of as to why it would do this and what these characters actually are? Below is the query I'm using. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT wmsys.wm_concat(userFirstName) AS firstNames
  FROM   COURSESECTION
  JOIN   CLASSCOORDINATOR on classcoord_sectionId = coursesect_sectionId
  JOIN   usr_USER on classcoord_coordinatorId = userId
GROUP BY classcoord_sectionId;
```

If I use the same query but use a dump(wmsys.wm_concat(columnName)) then I get the data presented in the picture below.

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_VSEi5_hEznA/TDx2dle4BmI/AAAAAAAAAEM/cP6opWer-Go/concat.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_VSEi5_hEznA/TDx2dle4BmI/AAAAAAAAAEM/cP6opWer-Go/concat.jpg)

Comment: Are these characters what you see in SQL Plus?  SQL Developer?  In a browser, and which one if so?  And what is the datatype -- those look like 2 characters per letter.

Comment: These characters get displayed when viewing the result set through oracle sql developer. If I export the data to xls they also get displayed. If exporting to xml they become spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DUMP is my starting point when investigating character set issues.

```
select wmsys.wm_concat('êõôó'), dump(wmsys.wm_concat('êõôó')) 
from dual connect by level < 3;
```

In my database (AL32UTF8 as shown by querying the NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter from v$nls_parameters), this returns as expected.

How does selecting a simple userFirstName show up ?

I'd suspect that the values have come from a multi-character set environment but have somehow been treated as single character set data.

---

Edited to add:

I'm able to reproduce this using the following:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';

AL16UTF16

create table t (v nvarchar2(3));
insert into t values ('a');
select dump(v) from t;
select wmsys.wm_concat(v), v, dump(v), dump(wmsys.wm_concat(v)) from t
group by v;
```

To remedy, you could try casting the string to a standard VARCHAR2

```
select wmsys.wm_concat(cast(v as varchar2(3)))
from t
group by v;
```

Comment: When I do a select with dump(wmsys.wm_concat(userFirstName)) the result set comes back with each character number separated by a 0 character number(pictured above). Is this what you were asking?